# Goog Cloud Storage Acl and or buckets with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I can't wrap my head around this. I have a package for Laravel which basicly wraps the PHP Api for the Google Cloud Storage.
I can upload files into a bucket now. But now I am stuck with the users uploading to my bucket. I think it's bad to create a bucket for each user and nested buckets is not possible.
How can I list files that are uploaded by a specific user?
I found something about ACL: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists

Can someone tell me if this is the rigth approach? I mean, should I create a user on Google Cloud Storage for each registration on my website?
Is there a simple example for this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create user for uploading files and also do one thing create a folder In your bucket then you will get specific path as a base url used this url and then in this url upload your image file with specific name that you have to give. Once it will upload just pick this url store in your database table. Than you can use this link for access image easily.

Comment: But over here I can only see the createBucket() method, not a method to create a folder: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.72.0/storage/storageclient

Answer (score 0):

It will depends on the design of your app. An approach that you can follow is (very similar to what Rohan said): to use the user Id you get when a user authenticates to your app, and to create a folder that you would use to upload all objects for that specific user. So it will be easier to manage (create, update, delete) all objects that belongs to the user. When you delete the user from your app you can also delete the folder. For this you will need a single [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) that will be used to authenticate your app to the GCS bucket.

When you upload the object you also specify the path (folder). Look at this [example](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.72.0/storage/bucket?method=upload).

Comment: What is the sample?

Comment: $options = [
    'resumable' => true,
    'name' => '/images/new-name.jpg',
    'metadata' => [
        'contentLanguage' => 'en'
    ]
];

$object = $bucket->upload(
    fopen(__DIR__ . '/image.jpg', 'r'),
    $options
);